# CakePHP 4 Bake Custom TemplateCommand in Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-bake

I cannot seem to override `TemplateCommand` from my plugin.

Original `TemplateCommand` located here: `vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/TemplateCommand.php`

```
namespace Bake\Command;

...

class TemplateCommand extends BakeCommand
{...}
```

I stored mine here: `plugins/MyPlugin/src/Command/TemplateCommand`:

```
namespace MyPlugin\Bake\Command;

...

use Bake\Command\TemplateCommand as MyTemplateCommand;

class TemplateCommand extends MyTemplateCommand
{...}
```

When I run `bin/cake bake template books -t "MyPlugin"`, I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class MyPlugin\Bake\Command\TemplateCommand, because the name is already in use in C:\path\to\app\plugins\MyPlugin\src\Command\TemplateCommand.php on line 39
```

**Edit #2**

In `Plugin.php`, in `bootstrap()`, I was able to debug loaded plugins.

```
[
        (int) 0 => 'AuditStash',
        (int) 1 => 'Bake',
        (int) 2 => 'DebugKit',
        (int) 3 => 'Migrations',
        (int) 4 => 'MyPlugin'
]
```

**Edit #3**

In `plugins/MyPlugin/src/Command/TemplateCommand.php`, I added `***MYPLUGIN***` to the output.

```
namespace MyPlugin\Command;

...

use Bake\Command\TemplateCommand as MyPluginTemplateCommand;

class TemplateCommand extends MyPluginTemplateCommand
{
    ...
    public function bake(
        Arguments $args,
        ConsoleIo $io,
        string $template,
        $content = '',
        ?string $outputFile = null
    ): void {
        if ($outputFile === null) {
            $outputFile = $template;
        }
        if ($content === true) {
            $content = $this->getContent($args, $io, $template);
        }
        if (empty($content)) {
            $io->err("<warning>No generated content for '{$template}.php', not generating template.</warning>");

            return;
        }
        $path = $this->getTemplatePath($args);
        $filename = $path . Inflector::underscore($outputFile) . '.php';

        $io->out("\n" . sprintf('***MYPLUGIN*** Baking `%s` view template file...', $outputFile), 1, ConsoleIo::QUIET);
        $io->createFile($filename, $content, $args->getOption('force'));
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run `bin/bake template books -t MyPlugin`, I see this message without my added prefix:

`Baking` index `view template file...`

It doesn't seem to pickup my class.

**Edit #4**

In `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php`, function `run`, I added `var_dump`:

```
...
$shell = $this->getCommand($io, $commands, $name);
var_dump($commands);
...
```

Output:

```
object(Cake\Console\CommandCollection)#33 (1) {
  ["commands":protected]=>
  array(87) {
    ["help"]=>
    string(32) "Cake\Console\Command\HelpCommand"
    ["version"]=>
    string(27) "Cake\Command\VersionCommand"
    ["cache clear"]=>
    string(30) "Cake\Command\CacheClearCommand"
    ["cache clear_all"]=>
    string(33) "Cake\Command\CacheClearallCommand"
    ["cache list"]=>
    string(29) "Cake\Command\CacheListCommand"
    ["completion"]=>
    string(30) "Cake\Command\CompletionCommand"
    ["i18n"]=>
    string(24) "Cake\Command\I18nCommand"
    ["i18n extract"]=>
    string(31) "Cake\Command\I18nExtractCommand"
    ["i18n init"]=>
    string(28) "Cake\Command\I18nInitCommand"
    ["plugin assets copy"]=>
    string(36) "Cake\Command\PluginAssetsCopyCommand"
    ["plugin assets remove"]=>
    string(38) "Cake\Command\PluginAssetsRemoveCommand"
    ["plugin assets symlink"]=>
    string(39) "Cake\Command\PluginAssetsSymlinkCommand"
    ["plugin load"]=>
    string(30) "Cake\Command\PluginLoadCommand"
    ["plugin loaded"]=>
    string(32) "Cake\Command\PluginLoadedCommand"
    ["plugin unload"]=>
    string(32) "Cake\Command\PluginUnloadCommand"
    ["routes check"]=>
    string(31) "Cake\Command\RoutesCheckCommand"
    ["routes"]=>
    string(26) "Cake\Command\RoutesCommand"
    ["routes generate"]=>
    string(34) "Cake\Command\RoutesGenerateCommand"
    ["schema_cache build"]=>
    string(36) "Cake\Command\SchemacacheBuildCommand"
    ["schema_cache clear"]=>
    string(36) "Cake\Command\SchemacacheClearCommand"
    ["server"]=>
    string(26) "Cake\Command\ServerCommand"
    ["console"]=>
    string(22) "App\Shell\ConsoleShell"
    ["model"]=>
    string(29) "MyPlugin\Command\ModelCommand"
    ["my_plugin.model"]=>
    string(29) "MyPlugin\Command\ModelCommand"
    ["template"]=>
    string(32) "MyPlugin\Command\TemplateCommand"
    ["my_plugin.template"]=>
    string(32) "MyPlugin\Command\TemplateCommand"
    ...
    string(25) "Bake\Command\ModelCommand"
    ["bake template"]=>
    string(28) "Bake\Command\TemplateCommand"
    ...
  }
}
```

In `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandScanner.php`, added `var_dump`:

```
public function scanPlugin(string $plugin): array
{
    if (!Plugin::isLoaded($plugin)) {
        return [];
    }
    $path = Plugin::classPath($plugin);
    $namespace = str_replace('/', '\\', $plugin);
    $prefix = Inflector::underscore($plugin) . '.';

    $commands = $this->scanDir($path . 'Command', $namespace . '\Command\\', $prefix, []);
    $shells = $this->scanDir($path . 'Shell', $namespace . '\Shell\\', $prefix, []);
    var_dump($commands);

    return array_merge($shells, $commands);
}
```

Output:

```
array(0) {
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(94) "C:\path\to\MyPlugin\src\CommandModelCommand.php"
    ["fullName"]=>
    string(15) "my_plugin.model"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "model"
    ["class"]=>
    string(29) "MyPlugin\Command\ModelCommand"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(97) "C:\path\to\MyPlugin\src\CommandTemplateCommand.php"
    ["fullName"]=>
    string(18) "my_plugin.template"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "template"
    ["class"]=>
    string(32) "MyPlugin\Command\TemplateCommand"
  }
}
...
```

**Edit #5**

I think I got it!

```
namespace MyPlugin\Command;

use Bake\Command\TemplateCommand as MyPluginTemplateCommand;

class TemplateCommand extends MyPluginTemplateCommand
{...}
```

I also moved the addition of my plugin on the last line of the `bootstrap()` function.

The output from the CLI now reflects the changes I made.

**Edit #6**

Need to figure out why it's not writing the views to the appropriate folder. It doubles up on books: `src/templates/Books/Books`

**Edit #7**

To get rid of the doubling in the path, commented out the function `getTemplatePath`.

**Edit #8**

Final solution.

The class definition used, updated Edit #5 too.

```
namespace MyPlugin\Command;

use Bake\Command\TemplateCommand as MyPluginTemplateCommand;

class TemplateCommand extends MyPluginTemplateCommand
{...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong, there is no `Bake` folder in the path to your class file. This mismatch will cause checks for the class' existence to fail, and subsequently cause the autoloader to load the file multiple times, resulting in the error that you're seeing, as a class can only be declared once.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to create `plugins/MyPlugin/src/Bake/Command` and move my class in there? This is what I did and the message goes away but it doesn't display my changes. I added an extra scaffoldActions and changed the output message `$io->out("\n" . sprintf('!!Modified!! Baking `%s` view template file...', $outputFile), 1, ConsoleIo::QUIET);`l

Comment: @TechFanDan No, I'm saying that you need to remove `Bake` from the namespace. Also note that overriding on name basis only works when your plugin is being loaded after the bake plugin.

Comment: Added output of loaded plugins. It would seem the order is correct?

Comment: I was sure my twig files were being picked up before asking this, but they don't seem to be. I no longer get errors, but it's not picking up my file as it's not showing the IO out messages nor does it list the extra scaffoldActions.

Comment: In 4.0, are Commands replacements for Shell/Tasks?

Comment: @TechFanDan Yes, they are.

Comment: Thanks. Can you comment on Edit #3? I don't get any errors during baking, but it's not outputting what I've added to my class (ie. ***MYPLUGIN***)

Comment: @TechFanDan Probably your command isn't being used. You'll have to do some debugging to pin down the problem, like what the final list of commands look like (`\Cake\Console\CommandRunner::run()`), what exactly command scanning returns (`\Cake\Console\CommandCollection::discoverPlugin()/resolveNames()`), etc. Also note that the command override would happen regardless of what theme you are using.

Comment: See edit #4. I think I did this right. It shows that my commands are in the list.

Comment: @TechFanDan If you look closely, something doesn't match up. Your command is being listed as `template`, and later on, there's `bake template`, which is what you actually wanted to override. This could mean that your plugin is loaded too early. Also your command's `defaultName()` method doesn't resolve to `bake template` (which is what you need and what should be the default), but to `template`. Also there seems to be a bug in how path's are picked up, but that should be unrelated.

Comment: See edit #5, I think we got it!